# Finding a value from 5 systems of equations of 5 variables(CHMMC 2014)

Tags: linear-algebra, contest-math, systems-of-equations

$$\text{For } a_1\cdots a_5\in \mathbb{R},$$
$$\frac{a_1}{k^2+1}+\cdots+\frac{a_5}{k^2+5}=\frac{1}{k^2}$$
$$\forall k=\{2,3,4,5,6\}$$
$$\text{Find }\frac{a_1}2+\cdots+\frac{a_5}6$$
The Provided explanation/official solution was
$$\text{Solution }1:\large{\frac{65}{72}}$$
Please don't mark this as off-topic, I have no clue where to start. Clearly it would not be feasible to compute $a_1\cdots a_5$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let
$$\sum_{i=1}^{5} \frac{a_i}{x+i} = \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$$ where $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $4$, and $Q$ of degree $5$. The coefficent of $x^4$ in $P(x)$ is $\sum a_i$ and $Q(x) = \prod_{k=1}^{5} (x+k)$

We get that

$$x P(x) - Q(x) = 0$$

as $0 = \dfrac{P(x)}{Q(x)} - \dfrac{1}{x} = \dfrac{x P(x) - Q(x)}{xQ(x)}$ for $x = 2^2, 3^2, \dots, 6^2$.

for $x = 2^2, 3^2, \dots, 6^2$
Thus $$xP(x) - Q(x)  = K \prod_{k=2}^6 (x - k^2)$$

(as $xP(x) - Q(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $5$, and leading coefficient $\sum a_i -1$)

We are looking at $$\frac{P(1)}{Q(1)} = \frac{Q(1) + K\prod_{k=2}^6 (1 - k^2)}{Q(1)}$$

Now $Q(1) = 6! = 720$
And $\prod_{k=2}^{6} (1-k^2) = -302400$

Now we need to figure out that value $K$. This we can, by setting $x=0$ in $$xP(x) - Q(x)  = K \prod_{k=2}^6 (x - k^2)$$

Comment: Nice solution!  (The leading coefficient of $x^4$ in $P(x)$ is actually $\sum a_i$, but it turns out that's not relevant to your solution.)

Comment: @Ted: You are right...

Comment: I need slightly more time to understand this solution, but will accept this when I finally do.

Comment: This is a very nice and effective strategy to solving this kind of questions.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from $\displaystyle \frac{a_1}{k^2+1}+\cdots+\frac{a_5}{k^2+5}=\frac{1}{k^2}$ we would like to plug in $k^2=1$ and get

$$ \frac{a_1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{a_5}{6}=1$$

In fact, the correct answer is slightly less.  We can add any function rational $f(k)$ which vanishes on all of $k^2 = 2,3,4,5,6$.  So are are going to define $f(x) = K \cdot \prod_{k=2}^6 (x - k^2)$ where $g(x)$ can be any polynomial.

$$ \frac{a_1}{x^2+1}+\cdots+\frac{a_5}{x^2+5}=\frac{1+ K \cdot \prod_{k=2}^6 (x - k^2)}{x^2} \tag{$\ast$}$$

If we set $x= 0$ the right side is undefined, but we can cross multiply:

\begin{eqnarray} x^2 \left( \frac{a_1}{x^2+1}+\cdots+\frac{a_5}{x^2+5} \right)&=&1+ K \cdot \prod_{k=2}^6 (x - k^2) \\ 
 0&=&1 - K \cdot 6!^2
\end{eqnarray}

We have that $\boxed{K = \frac{1}{6!^2}}$  Then plug $x=1$ into $(\ast)$

$$ \frac{a_1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{a_5}{6}=\frac{1+ K \cdot \prod_{k=2}^6 (x - k^2)}{x^2}  = 1 - \frac{(3\cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 6 \cdot 7)(1\cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5)}{6!^2 }$$

This argument is not quite seamless as the RHS is off by factor of 6.